Proving the discrete Laplace operator is an approximation of the continuous one
Given the lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d,$ one defines the discrete Laplace operator to be $$Hu(n) = - \sum_{\|m-n\|_1=1}(u(m)-u(n)), u:\mathbb{Z}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{C},$$ whereby the sum is running over all neighbor points of $n\in\mathbb{Z}^d$ where the laplacian is evaluated. In the continuous case we know that the laplacian is $\Delta u(x) = \nabla \cdot \nabla u = \sum_{k=1}^d \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x_k^2}.$ I would like to show that the discrete Laplace operator is an approximation of the continuous one. How should I proceed ? In case one approximates derivation by differences, there is a difference in both operators, since there is a single difference in the discrete case while there are second derivatives in the continuous one. Thus, I do not see how one would go, in some limit process, from the one operator into the other. Do you have any suggestion or a solution proposal ?

You must know that, in the case $n=2$, the classical dicrete "laplacian mask" is $\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\1&-4&1\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$ "tensorizing" the horizontal and vertical 1D masks $1,-2,1$ corresponding to the discrete second derivative. You juste have to take a nD equivalent tensor

I do not see what is meant by your notation. Can you extend this to an answer?

Have a look here.

I do not understand exactly what is meant and how can I work out the details.

See here
